# Class works locally, but not found when deployed

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Cloud Platform and Google App Engine to try to deploy an app to a staged live site, but when I use `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --version=staging --no-promote` and look at the site, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'NoahK\Hansel\Service\Database\FeesService' not
>   found in
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~project-hansel.421666723467090526/src/app/Provider/DatabaseServicesProvider.php on line 64

The actual code on line 64 doesn't matter. It's just trying to instantiate a FeesService object.  The real problem is that it's not finding the class even though it's included at the top of the file.  The app functions fine on my local dev server.  So why is this happening only when I deploy it?

Comment: maybe you used a local path at your local dev server, and that path is not in the environment you deployed to. you could to print out your environment variables both locally and "live" and compare what you got. somewhere there is probably a difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy a version, App Engine start it to be sure that it is valid/healthy, even if there is no traffic promote on it.

About the error, there is a strange thing

> `NoahK\Hansel\Service\Database\FeesService`

Backslash? I met the @niklas-rosencrantz remarks:

- Are you sure to update your path before/when deploying?

This one seems to be "Windows" format path, that is strange in linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the FeesService.php file was incorrectly named.  It's strange that this didn't produce an error locally but oh well.